# Lindenbaum's Lemma and the axiom of choice

Tags: first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

I have doubts about the connection between the theorem of completeness for first order logic and the axiom of choice. I did hear that AC (possibly in a weakened form) is necessary to prove Goedel theorem. In particular I was told that it was necessary to prove Lindenbaum lemma.

But I have studied [this [1]](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&lpg=PT126&vq=Lindenbaum%20%20lemma&pg=PT99#v=onepage&q&f=false) proof and it's not clear to me where are we using AC. Am I missing something or it's not this lemma the culprit?

*[1]: Mendelson E., "Introduction to Mathematical Logic", Prop. 2.14*

Comment: If you assume an existing enumeration of all formulas, AC is not explicitly needed.

Comment: "this proof" is meaningless. Especially since Google Books tells me that I cannot see that page. Can you provide an actual citation instead? And also maybe a gist of the proof?

Comment: @asaf-karagila Sorry, I added a citatation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked by Mauro in the comments, when the language you are concerned with is countable, or generally well-orderable, the axiom of choice is not needed. You can just enumerate (or otherwise well-order) your sentences and recursively extend the theory by taking anything which doesn't contradict your theory thus far, and by the end of the recursion you'd have a complete theory.

Indeed, this is a common theme. Choice is mainly needed to obtain a well-ordering of stuff.

In general, however, not every consistent theory can be extended to a complete theory. Perhaps because it has no model. For example, suppose that there exists a set $A$ which cannot be linearly ordered (e.g. an amorphous set). Consider the language in which we have a binary relation $<$ and a constant $c_a$ for all $a\in A$.

Now consider the following theory $T$:

1. $<$ is a linear order.
2. For any $a\neq b$, $c_a\neq c_b$.

This theory is consistent, of course, since contradiction would follow from a finite fragment of $T$, but any finite fragment has a [finite] model. But a complete theory extending $T$ would have to decide all the statements of the form $c_a<c_b$, which would in turn give you a linear ordering of $A$. Since no such linear ordering exists, there is no complete theory extending $T$.